# how can i access a remote folder with credentials in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I have a windows service and I'm using a  remote connection to access a folder and this folder has a password and a user that it is already specified down here in the code but it doesn't seem to access anyway I've already tried to do this locally and it works but when I do it remotely just doesn't work. any help would be great thank you!

```
Public Class Service1
    Dim cred As New NetworkCredential("Administrator", "*P4ssW0rD")


 Private Sub SchedularCallback(e As Object)
        'Metodo Procesa Archivos tipo boleano 

        Dim di As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo("\\132.147.161.83\SisInt\courts\agreement\J92016SEM2")

        For Each fi In di.GetFiles()

            'seleccionamos los archivos con las extensiones de Word
            If fi.Extension.ToUpper = ".DOC" Or fi.Extension.ToUpper = ".DOCX" Then
                ListaArchivos.Add(fi.FullName)
                ListaNombres.Add((fi.Name.Substring(0, fi.Name.Length - fi.Extension.Length)))

            End If

        Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Services operate in the security context of the account that's specified in the Services Control Panel, so you would need to change it there.

By default, the service only has access to local resources which is why you can't access anything outside the local machine.

Comment: thanks a lot! i think that is the problem, i have to wait to test it tomorrow because the server is at work but i checked the service like you told me and i  saw the fields where i have to put the missing information, thanks a lot again

Comment: I'm happy to help!

Comment: just to be safe, I don't have to add anything else in my code right?

Comment: Nope. Assuming you don't change it programmatically, the security context will be the login you set in the services control panel.

Comment: No problem. I just spent the last 6 months writing services. 8-)

Comment: hi I'm sorry to bother you again I just did what you told me I changed it to network service instead of local service in the services.msc window but now it won't let me initialize it do you have any guide or something? sorry I bother you so much

Comment: You're getting close. 8-) While the NetworkService account does have permissions on the network, it has little else and almost certainly doesn't have permission to whatever you're trying to access remotely. The account you specify in the Service Control Panel needs to have whatever permissions your service needs to use. For example, if your service is going to print somewhere, the account it runs as needs to have permissions to the print queue it's going to use.

Comment: done i've already give the permissions to my service and now i can initialize it, look the function of my service is to send e-mails automatically taking all information necesary from a database, before doing the tests in the remote folder I tried it locally and it works but when i try to test it remotely it just doesn't access the folder and i just don't know why :(

Comment: You'll need to step through it with the debugger and find out what the problem is. You can start the service then attach to it in Visual Studio With Debug -> Attach To Process, then step through it and see where it fails.